# Rails + Backbone.js: Having trouble accessing objects in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom, view, backbone.js, coffeescript

got a problem for a couple of days with backbone and can't figure out a way to solve it or find a solution on stackoverflow.

I use Rails 3.1 + latest backbone (+ coffeescript):

Here is one of my views as an example (same problem in all of them):

```
Blog.Views.Payment ||= {}

class Blog.Views.Payment.PaymentView extends Backbone.View
  className:  'payment_method'
  tagName:    'td'
  events:
    'click #renderPayment':  'renderPayment'

  initialize: ->
    # CAN'T access @options.payment_methods here 
    @options.payment_methods.bind(###stuff###)

  render: ->
    # CAN'T access @options.payment_methods here either...
    $(@el).html ("### something with #{@options.payment_methods or @options.payment_methods.model}")
    return @

  updateView: ()->
    # updating view stuff...

  renderPayment:  ->
    # ACCESSING @options.payment_methods fine here!!!
    if ($("#payment_details").length == 0)
      $(@el).append("<ul id='payment_details'>
                       <li id='payment_type'>#{@options.payment_methods.get(1).get('payment_type')}</li>
                     </ul>
                       ").effect("highlight", 700)
```

In the first two cases when I run the example the browser tells me that @options.payment_methods is not defined, third case working fine.

Second thing is that I can't access any DOM elements that are already "hardcoded" into the page and are not created by the Javascript. I know the reason for that and have been reading a loooot of posts here on Stackoverflow about it but I couldn't get any solution to work. Any hints greatly appreciated.

Best regards,
Phil

EDIT:
It seems that it has something to do with the timing of access of the objects on the page, similiar to the access of the hardcoded DOM elements of the page. If I edit my view as follows I can't access @options.payment_methods anymore even if I was able to before at that point in the code.

```
# changed "renderPayment" to "$(document).ready" or just "$" in coffeescript
$  ->
  # ACCESS NOT possible anymore
  if ($("#payment_details").length == 0)
    $(@el).append("<ul id='payment_details'>
                     <li id='payment_type'>#{@options.payment_methods.get(1).get('payment_type')}</li>
                   </ul>
                     ").effect("highlight", 700)
```

EDIT2: added my corresponding router file: (this is simply a modified version of the backbone-rails gem example "Blog")

```
class Blog.Routers.PostsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  initialize: (options) ->
    @posts = new Blog.Collections.PostsCollection()
    @posts.reset options.posts

    # ... other collections

    # fetch payment_methods collection
    @payment_methods = new Blog.Collections.PaymentMethodsCollection()
    @payment_methods.reset options.payment_methods
    @payment_methods.fetch()

    @model = ({posts: @posts, mails: @mails, addresses: @addresses, purchases: @purchases, payment_methods: @payment_methods})

  routes:
    "/new"            : "newPost"
    "/index"          : "index"
    "/:id/edit"       : "edit"
    "/:id"            : "show"
    ".*"              : "index"


  # main view
  index:  ->

    # render Product Info View
    @view = new Blog.Views.Product.ProductView(purchases: @purchases)
    $("#product_1").html(@view.render().el)

    ##### view etc.

    # render Payment View
    @view5 = new Blog.Views.Payment.PaymentView(payment_methods: @payment_methods)
    $("#customer_1").append(@view5.render().el)

   ### other views...
```

And my Payment model:

```
class Blog.Models.PaymentMethod extends Backbone.Model
  paramRoot: 'payment_method'

  defaults:
    payment_type: null
    # ...

class Blog.Collections.PaymentMethodsCollection extends Backbone.Collection
  model: Blog.Models.PaymentMethod
  url: '/payment_methods'
```

Comment: I may be wrong but the symptoms of your problem seem to match with the ones over here - http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/11/09/backbone-js-object-literals-views-events-jquery-and-el/

Comment: Hehe thanks! I stumbled upon that post yesterday since it really seemed to match my symptoms. Still no success! :-/

Answer (score 0):

You really need to look up and understand the difference between `->` and `=>`. It looks like most methods in your classes are using `->`, when they should be using `=>`. Whereever you use `@something`, it's really a shortcut to `this.something`, and `=>` makes sure that `this` really is what you expect it to be. With a `->`, `this` will be bound to whatever it is in the function that makes the call, not your class instance.

Answer (score 0):

Options are passed to a view's initialize method. So you can access them directly that way.

```
initialize: (options) ->
  # Now you have options
  options.payment_methods.bind(###stuff###)
```

Calling `@options` in `render()` should be fine, except in the event that render is not being called in the context of your view, ie from some other callback. To fix this, define `render` with the fat arrow, and it will always be called in the context of the view.

```
render: =>
  $(@el).html( ...etc...)
```

If you want to access elements that are already on the page, then there are a few things you need to do. Most importantly, pass the DOM element in `el` to the view constructor, and your view will "take over" and own that element. For example..

```
view = new Blog.Views.Payment.PaymentView(
  el: $("#product_whatever").get(0)
)
```

Then in that view, you want to scope your jQuery finds to the view's element. For example:

```
render: =>
  $(@el).find('div.somewhere_else').html("change this")
```

The backbone shortcut for this in coffeescript is

```
@$('div.somewhere_else').html(...)
```

Good luck

Comment: @maxlOrd thanks a lot for your explanation. In "render: =>" if I do "    alert @options.payment_methods.get(1).get('payment_type')" it gives me the error "this.options.payment_methods.get(1) is undefined" but still displays the alert with the correct data. any thoughts?

Comment: Make sure that the code that instantiates Blog.Routers.PostsRouter, and kicks off this whole thing, is running after document ready?